# How to connect to MySql database which situated in Remote lan network?

Tags: mysql, database-connection, jdbc-odbc

I want to connect the MYSQL database which is situaded in my lan home network.
I am using JDBC/ODBC connector.

Answer (score 0):

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://ip_addressof_host:3306/db_name", "username", "password");
```

Use above java code. You must give the ip address of the host machine.

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to make Port Forward TCP 3306 from external IP address to internal IP address of your  server which located in your home.

There are a lot of variants of instruction depends of your home Gateway.